# how to change Pandas dataframe to dictionary with key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

df = pd.DataFrame(ord_book).groupby('event_id').agg({'amount':'sum','pending_quantity':'sum'})..
print(df),,
pandas dataframe:

event_id,        amount ,         pending_quantity

32,                   250.0  ,        4.788398
33,         250.0     ,     5.380083

I am using df.to_dict()...i get
{'amount': {'32': 250.0, '33': 250.0}, 'pending_quantity': {'32': 4.788398200634525, '33': 5.380082793859557}}..this type of data

my expected answer is below:
event_id : 32, amount:250, quantity : 4.788398200634525,
event_id : 33, amount:250, quantity : 5.380082793859557,

Anyone know the answer,pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Add `as_index=False` and `sort=False` parameters to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and the `orient='records'` to [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(ord_book).groupby('event_id', as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg({'amount':'sum','pending_quantity':'sum'}))

d = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ord_book).groupby('event_id', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
        
d = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: first method is works fine...thanks for You!!!

Comment: one help...i get list = [ { user,name },{ user,name },etc...]..my question is how to get first 10 data in the list...